# Convert a multiline key:value string to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert a multiline key:value string to JSON.  Reason is I need to create HTTP headers out of it for an ajax request
sample data

content-type:text
host:myhost.com

I want it to become

```
{"content-type":"text",
"host":"myhost.com" }
```

I tried playing around and checked some documents and this is the best I got from Github

```
strToJSON = (str) => {
let commaAdded = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',').trim().replace(/,+$/g, '')
let items = commaAdded.split(',')
let jsonString = items.map(item => {
  return item.replace(/([^:]+)(:)(.+$)/, (match, p1, p2, p3) => {
    return `"${p1.trim()}": "${p3.trim()}"`
  })
}).join(', ')
try {
  return JSON.parse(`{${jsonString}}`)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

}

This works fine but the format is incorrect.
I got this instead:

```
{content-type:"text",
host:"myhost.com" }
```

the double quotes are missing from the keys.
I tried logging the jsonString before parsing it and the format is good. but once it is parsed using JSON.parse, the doublequote went missing

I hope someone can enlighten me what else I forgot to add.

Answer (score 0):

your function `strToJSON` outputs a javascript object. you'd need to convert it into a JSON string if you want JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(strToJSON("content-type:text host:myhost.com"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it too. but when I send it as headers in an ajax request, it is not read well. :(

Comment: here is the function call to convert:
params.header = JSON.stringify(strToJSON($('#request-header').val()));

Then I put the header in an ajax request

Comment: <code>
function sendRequest(url,method,headers,requestdata){
//Send ajax
  console.log(headers)
 $.ajax({
         "url": url,
         "type": method,
          "data":requestdata,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "processData": false,
          "xhrFields": { withCredentials: true },
          "headers":headers,
       /*  "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },*/
         success: function (response) {
           console.log("user is logged in")   
        }
      })
  //end of function returns response.
}</code>